# Space between two table not working on outlook

Tags: html, css, outlook

I'm working with two tables in html, but they don't look the same in Outlook as they do on the web.
Please see the image below for reference on how the table should be set up.
Is there other way to use aside from margin code in css.

Image on Outlook: [There's no space between two table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yk80L.jpg)

Image when using web: https://i.stack.imgur.com/MTY3v.jpg

```html
<body>
    <table>
        <tr>

            <td class="htitle">
                
           <br> <b style="font-size: 22px;">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</b></br>
            </td>
        </tr>
        
    </table>
    
    <div>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <p style='margin-left: 20pt;margin-top: 15pt;margin-right: 20pt;'>Hi, <b>[username]</b></p>
            
        </td>
    </tr>

</table>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Above is my sample code

Comment: Font size and line height must be declared.
Refer to
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43375714/outlook-2016-adds-space-between-table-rows-html-email-dev-cant-find-a-fix-tha

Comment: I tried using line height but it seems like when using outlook there's still no space between two table.